# Inject value inside annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to insert a value stored in a configuration file (eg: application.properties) inside java annotation as follows :

```
@MyAnnotation(name="${application.prop1}")
```

and in application.properties I have:

```
application.prop1=foo
```

So that at runtime I have :

```
@MyAnnotation(name="foo")
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I'd love a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I don't think this is possible. Spring has no idea about your annotation and doesn't know what to do with it. Even if you try to use @Value(..) on top of your `String name() default ""` (inside of your annotation), Spring still won't make this happen as the annotation is not a bean. Trying to make your annotation a bean won't work either as far as I can tell. It sound like you are going to have to come up with some type of processor for this.

Perhaps looking into the following topics might help give you some ideas on how to put this together:

- Auto Configuration: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-auto-configuration
- SPeL: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-expression-language
- Java Reflection: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html

And of course, there's always the possibility that you might want to step back and consider why you want to do this? What are you trying to achieve that perhaps can be done a more "out of the box" way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, yse `@Value` annotation

`@Value("property1")`

Comment: I need to have the value resolved inside _@MyAnnotation_ not in an attribute

Comment: Then write code that will detect such annotation and resolve it using SpEL for you. Your annotation - your trouble.